# How to reuse same mixed code snippets by both PHP and JS? Best practice?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, reusability

I'm just starting to learn JavaScript and PHP and am having troubles with this seemingly simple problem - how do I code reusable HTML snippets so they can be used both for JS and PHP?

Here's a case example - I have a simple .php page like this:

```
<body> <?php

    foreach( $members_array as $member ) {

        $id = $member->id;
        $name = $member->name;
        $img = $member->get_img();

        include( 'single-member.php' );
    }

    foreach( $other_members_array as $member ) {

        $id = $member->id;
        $name = $member->name; ?>

        <button type="button" onclick="addExtraMember" data-user-id="<?= $id? >">ADD <?= $name ?></button> <?php

    }

</body>
```

Where for each member in the array a html code is dynamically generated with the variables. The 'single-member.php' is this:

```
<div id="<?= $id ?>">
    <img src="<?= $img ?>">
    <p><?= $name ?></p>
</div>
```

Then when the page finishes loading all the members are listed. The user of the page can click on one of the $other_members_array buttons that calls a JavaScript function. This JavaScript function should add the same code as 'single-member.php' after the last 'single-member.php' element to keep with visual consistency and in case I need to change the structure and styling of the snippet it's only in one file. I was googling this all afternoon today and here are my basic solutions:

1. rename the file to .html then load() and replace the attributes and text fields in JS
2. via .php page include one extra 'single-member.php' with empty values, a unique id and without displaying it so JS could grab it from the HTML DOM for re-use (in case the $members_array is empty)
3. don't load the members via PHP, add them all with JS when the page finishes loading using a reworked 'single-member.html' snippet without the PHP variables. So when a button is pressed JS function can use the 'single-member.html' again

I have a feeling this is a common problem - reusing elements and snippets between JS and PHP so I was wondering what the best practice is?

Also am I missing some more elegant library or solution?